# Setter in child component compiles but raises and error

Tags: typescript, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

In my component I have this simple visibility parameter:

```
<template>
  <b-modal :visible.sync="_modalVisible" size="md" title="Add new event group" centered header-bg-variant="light" ok-title="Add" ok-variant="info" @hide="hideModal()">
    Hello.
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "AddNewEventGroupModal",
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },

  props: {
    // Variables.
    modalVisible: Boolean
  },

  computed: {
    _modalVisible: {
      get: function () {
        return this.modalVisible; // ERROR here!!
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    hideModal() {
      this.$emit("toggle-visibility", false);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

However, this code WORKS (Compiled successfully), but soon after raises an ERROR:

> Property 'modalVisible' does not exist on type '(() => any) |
> ComputedOptions'. Property 'modalVisible' does not exist on type
> '() => any'.

I would like to understand WHY this happens and also how to fix it. It is interesting to see that it works (the functionality is OK and it compiled), but still raises an error.

In case it is important: Parent calls the child like this:

```
<add-new-event-group-modal :modalVisible.sync="addNewVisibility" :eventGroupApi="eventGroupApi" :newEventGroup="newEventGroup" @toggle-visibility="toggleAddNewVisibility"></add-new-event-group-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `:visible.sync="_modalVisible"`, I guess at some point the the computed variable `_modalVisible` will get updated, the problem is, it has no setter, try to add one.

```
computed: {
    _modalVisible: {
        get: function () {
            return this.modalVisible; // ERROR here!!
        },
        set(val) {
            this.modalVisible = val;
        }
    }
},
```